# python PCA Regenerating loadings using eigen vectors and eigen values

Tags: pca, python

I am trying the following:

```
from sklearn.decomposition.pca import PCA
import numpy as np
Data =  np.random.rand(300,5)
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(Data)
Facs = pca.components_ #rows are loadings
w, v = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(np.transpose(Data))) #v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]
print Facs[0,:]
print v[:,0]*np.sqrt(w[0])
```

Now according to the python documentation:
Facs[0,:] should match exactly v[:,0]*np.sqrt(w[0])

But it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Fixed the code to call Data.

Documentation saying that v is normalized eigen vectors is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html)

Blog showing that pca.components_ is loadings is [here](http://nxn.se/post/36838219245/loadings-with-scikit-learn-pca). However, the [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) does not verify the blog's statement. So, blog is wrong probably.

Hence to get the loadings I need to do:

```
v[:,0]*np.sqrt(w[0])
```

Am I correct in saying that ?

Comment: This is a deadly language/package specific question formulation. Might you want to show your data and your results - so that more people could appreciate and answer?

Comment: I have added the print statements. The code above should be self sufficient. Also since I am using the random numbers to generate the intial matrix it would be impossible for someone else to recreate the numbers. But if you run the code you will see the difference.

Comment: Your code doesn't even run.  What is `ClassResids` and where does it come from?

Comment: Also you can make "random" numbers reproducible.  In python / numpy, use `np.random.seed()` directly before "random" data generation.

Comment: Finally, can you edit your question to link to the documentation that is relevant?  If (see my answer) some documentation somewhere says that multiplying by `np.sqrt(w[0])` really is necessary, that is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does because:

1. you put some exogenous variable `ClassResids` instead of `Data` in your call to `np.transpose()`.
2. you are multiplying by `np.sqrt(w[0])` which is not necessary.  `v[:, 0]` is equal to `facs[0, :]`
3. `np.linalg.eig()` doesn't return eigenvectors in any particular order, but the scikit `pca()` method does.  That means that the elements of `v` will be the same as the elements of `facs`, but the arrangement of the matrices will be different.
4. PCA decompositions of these types are invariant to sign-flips on all the eigenvalues.

This code (which btw is reformatted to conform to python standards by lowercasing variable names and using spaces around commas and operators) does what I think you want.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition.pca import PCA

def test_pca_eigenvector_equivalence(seed, n_dim = 2):
    """
    Determine if np.linalg.eig returns the same results as sklearn PCA method.
    """
    def almost_equal(arr1, arr2):
        return np.all(np.isclose(arr1, arr2))

    def sorted_abs_elements(arr):
        return np.sort(np.abs(arr.reshape(-1)))

    np.random.seed(seed)
    data = np.random.rand(50, n_dim)
    pca = PCA()
    pca.fit(data)
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(data.transpose())) 

    # test matrix equivalence: do matrices have the same elements at each position
    matrix_equivalence = almost_equal(pca.components_, 
                                      v.transpose())

    # test element equivalence: is a sorted 1D list of absolute values of elements the same?
    elements_v = sorted_abs_elements(v)
    elements_pca = sorted_abs_elements(pca.components_)

    element_equivalence = almost_equal(elements_v, elements_pca)
    return matrix_equivalence, element_equivalence

seed_list = range(10)

[test_pca_eigenvector_equivalence(s) for s in seed_list]
```

---

The output is:

```
[(False, True),
 (True, True),
 (False, True),
 (False, True),
 (False, True),
 (False, True),
 (False, True),
 (False, True),
 (False, True),
 (True, True)]
```

So for 10 random tests of 2-dimensional data, the `v` and `facs` matrices were precisely identical two times.  However, every time, no matter what the random data used was, the *elements* of `v` were the same as the *elements* of `facs` (except for possible sign changes).

Comment: Curt please see my edits

Comment: I found an additional problem and am updating my answer.  In general, `np.linalg.eig()` doesn't return the eigenvectors or eigenvalues in a sorted order, but the scikit `PCA()` routines do.

Comment: v and Fcas are eigenvectors and not loadings. For loadings, I need to multiply v with w? Am I thinking it right?